# É possível evitar que o Wine pegue vírus? ou ele já é imune por rodar sobre Linux e Mac?

Tags: linux, mac, antivirus

Sabemos que há vírus para MAC e Linux, esta não é a questão, a questão é se é possível usar aplicativos Windows usando Wine sem contaminar com vírus, este já é nativamente imune a maioria do vírus ou é preciso usar um Antivírus?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A resposta é não. O fato de usar Wine não te deixa imune a vírus. Qualquer tipo de malware é código rodando em seu computador e eles podem sim rodar no Wine.

Existe uma página no Wiki do Wine mostrando o que pode ser feito para se proteger: http://wiki.winehq.org/SecuringWine

Deve-se ter em mente, entretanto, que como os vírus são, em sua maioria esmagadora, feitos para o ambiente Windows eles muito provavelmente não rodarão conforme o esperado no Linux. Um vírus é programado usando vários tipos de hacks baseados em uma instalação padrão do Windows ([ver esta reposta](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/1735)). Ao rodar em um ambiente como o Wine, certas chamadas e verificações não funcionarão conforme o esperado e isso impedirá o vírus de funcionar corretamente.

A não ser, obviamente, que o vírus tenha sido programado para identificar que está rodando no Wine e a partir daí fazer algo. É exatamente por isso que certas recomendações básicas como não rodar o Wine com privilégios de root devem ser seguidas. Ao rodar como root você estaria deixando seu sistema vulnerável para que o vírus apague os seus arquivos ou mesmo critografe-os, com o objetivo de cobrar pela descritografia depois.

Para dar essa reposta fiz algumas pesquisas e está é uma dúvida recorrente na comunidade. A minha percepção geral é que embora exista a possibilidade de um vírus afetar o Linux (pelo Wine), a probabilidade é pequena.

Sobre o Antivírus, você pode rodar o ClamAV.

Algumas perguntas:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/5031/what-if-i-run-a-virus-trojan-windows-exe-on-ubuntu-with-wine

https://askubuntu.com/questions/49255/risks-disadvantages-associated-with-wine

https://askubuntu.com/questions/562388/do-wine-viruses-only-work-while-wine-is-running

https://askubuntu.com/questions/361781/could-autorun-virus-affect-my-pc-via-wine